# How to merge two different array of object in JavaScript? Check below example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, merge

Input Arrays:

```
var array1 = [
  {
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];
```

Result:

```
var results = [
  {
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something',
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever',
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AngouLongjam … Regarding all the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, perhaps this is acceptable? Simply looping over the first array and using the index to select the correct object from the second array.

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];

var result = [];

array1.forEach((itm, idx, _)  => { 
  result.push({ ...itm, ...array2[idx] });
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) along with [`spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the values from the two arrays.

```js
const array1 = [ { PersonalID: '11', qusetionNumber: '1', value: 'Something' }, { PersonalID: '12', qusetionNumber: '2', value: 'whatever' }, ];
const array2 = [ { uniqueId: '111' }, { uniqueId: '222' }, ];

const result = array1.map((el, idx) => ({ ...el, ...array2[idx]}));   
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided approaches one also could implement callback functions for ...

- a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach where the callback utilizes the `map` methods 2nd [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) parameter for providing the 2nd array (the OP's `array2`).
- a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach where the callback gets the 2nd array (the OP's `array2`) provided as property of the `reduce` methods 2nd parameter, its [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters).

In both cases [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is one possible way of creating a merged object which is loosely decoupled from both of its source items.

Unlike all the other so far provided solutions both suggested ways have in common that each implementation is agnostic to the OP's outer-scope array-references. And due to being provided as function statements the code is re-usable as well.

```js
const array1 = [{
  PersonalID: '11',
  qusetionNumber: '1',
  value: 'Something'
}, {
  PersonalID: '12',
  qusetionNumber: '2',
  value: 'whatever'
}];

const array2 = [{
  uniqueId: '111'
}, {
  uniqueId: '222'
}];


function mergeWithBoundArraysRelatedItem(item, idx) {
  return Object.assign({}, item, this[idx]);  
}
console.log(
  '`map` based ...\n\n',
  'array1.map(mergeWithBoundArraysRelatedItem, array2) =>',
  array1
    .map(mergeWithBoundArraysRelatedItem, array2)
);

function mergeRelatedArrayItems({ result, source }, item, idx) {
  result.push(
    Object.assign({}, item, source[idx])
  );
  return { result, source };
}
console.log(
  '`reduce` based ...\n\n',
  'array1.reduce(mergeRelatedArrayItems, { source: array2, result: [] }).result =>',
  array1
    .reduce(mergeRelatedArrayItems, {
      source: array2, result: [],
    })
    .result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];

const fun =(ar , ar2)=>{
  for(let [k , v] of Object.entries(ar2)){
    for(x in v){
      ar[k][x] = v[x]
}  
}
  return ar
}
console.log(fun(array1 , array2))
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];
// if you don't want array1 to be modified use instead
// Array.from(array1).map(function(e,i){return Object.assign(e,array2[i])})
array1.map(function(e,i){return Object.assign(e,array2[i])})

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: With `Object.assign(e, array2[i])` one mutates every item of `array1`. It might be better to slightly change it to `Object.assign({}, e, array2[i])`.

Answer (score -2):

I can also use `Object.assign`

```js
var array1 = [{
    PersonalID: '11',
    qusetionNumber: '1',
    value: 'Something'
  },
  {
    PersonalID: '12',
    qusetionNumber: '2',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
];

var array2 = [{
    uniqueId: '111'
  },
  {
    uniqueId: '222'
  },
];



let myArr = []
for(let i = 0 ; i<array1.length ; i++){
myArr.push(Object.assign(array1[i], array2[i]))
}

console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: With `Object.assign(array1[i], array2[i])` one mutates every item of `array1`. It might be better to slightly change it to `Object.assign({}, array1[i], array2[i])`.